# snakemake: wildcards are changing in input function

Tags: snakemake

I'm having a problem with the following rule, it seems like the wild card is changing half way through.

```
> maker_flow={'boot1':'init', 'boot2':'boot1', 'final':'boot2'} #this defines the bootstraping workflow {now:last}
> rule maker:
>     input: snap= 'another_file_string_with_same_'.format(), gff=lambda wc: 'maker/{lrun}/{name}_{lrun}.maker.output/{name}_{lrun}.all.gff'.format(lrun=maker_flow[wc.run], name=config['proj']['name'])
>     output:   master='another_file_string_with_same'.format(), gff='maker/{{run}}/{name}_{{run}.maker.output/{name}_{{run}}.all.gff'.format(name=config['proj']['name'])
```

When I comment out the `gff` input the code will run. Otherwise I get:

```
rule maker:
    input: maker/init/snap/hmm/test_10l_init.snap_hmm, maker/init/test_10l_init.maker.output/test_10l_init.all.gff
    output: maker/boot1/test_10l_boot1.maker.output/test_10l_boot1_master_datastore_index.log, maker/boot1/test_10l_boot1.maker.output/test_10l_boot1.all.gff
    log: /gpfs/projects/bgmp/shared/lizards/test_data/sandbox/snake/logs/test_10l_boot1_maker.log
    jobid: 4
    wildcards: run=boot1

InputFunctionException in line 95 of /gpfs/projects/bgmp/shared/lizards/test_data/sandbox/snake/Snakefile:
KeyError: 'init'
Wildcards:
run=init
```

Which doesn't make much sense, since the input for the gff file seems to have successfully resolved. And the wildcard seems to have changed.

There is another rule which creates the 'init' files

```
rule maker_init:
    output:
        'maker/{run}/{name}_{run}.maker.output/{name}_{run}_master_datastore_index.log'.format(name=config['proj']['name'], run='init'), gff=protected('maker/init/{name}_{run}.maker.output/{name}_init.all.gff'.format(name=config['proj']['name'], run='init'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When evaluating the rule for run=boot1, snakemake sees that it needs the file "maker/init/test_10l_init.maker.output/test_10l_init.all.gff". Is this file supposed to already exist? If so, it seems like snakemake isn't seeing it, because instead it sees that it can use the maker rule pattern to create this file (so now it's evaluating the rule with run=init, hence the wildcard change) but when it tries to lookup the key 'init' in maker_flow, it gets a KeyError.

Comment: Yes, the file is created in the maker_init rule. Is there anyway I can try to prevent snake make from behaving like this? I've tried ruleorder: make_init>maker. Also both file inputs use the same wildcard. Does that mean that each file has independent wildcards?

Comment: If ruleorder: make_init > maker didn't work, then it's possible there's something wrong with make_init so snakemake doesn't see it as a choice for creating the init file. Without the ruleorder line, if snakemake sees that both rules can create a file then it would give you an error about ambiguous rules. I can't see what the problem is with maker_init, though. You could try wildcard_constraints to limit what the wildcard can be in each rule. I'd change 'final' to 'bootFinal' or something, and try wildcard_constraints: run='boot.*'